# Check if a node.js module is available

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to find out if a module is available.

For example, I want to check if the module `mongodb` is available, programmatically.

Also, it shouldn't halt the program if a module isn't found, I want to handle this myself.

<sub>PS: I added this question because Google isn't helpful.</sub>

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a more clever way if you only want to check whether a module is available (but not load it if it's not):

```
function moduleAvailable(name) {
    try {
        require.resolve(name);
        return true;
    } catch(e){}
    return false;
}

if (moduleAvailable('mongodb')) {
    // yeah we've got it!
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is the most clever way I found to do this. If anyone has a better way to do so, please point it out.

```
var mongodb;
try {
    mongodb = require( 'mongodb' );
}
catch( e ) {
    if ( e.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' ) {
        // The module hasn't been found
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful using this with your own modules. `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` will be called if a nested require fails. To avoid this a regex could be used on the message to check which module was not found. It would be advisable to print the actual error message to the console. Using `require.resolve` first would avoid this too.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better if it were to rethrow the error if it isn't MODULE_NOT_FOUND?

Answer (score 1):

For ECMAScript modules (ESM) since Node 12 the `import` keyword can also be [used as function](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) that returns a Promise:

```js
import("mongodb")
  .then(mongodb => {
    // use module
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e)) // The module hasn't been found
```

or

```
async main() {
  const mongodb = import("mongodb")
  // use module
}

main().catch(e => console.error(e)) // module hasn't been found or other error
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `resolve`-like modules will be helpfully here?

The numbers of modules are exist on npm:

- [async-resolve](https://github.com/Meettya/async-resolve)
- [resolve](https://github.com/substack/node-resolve)
- [resolveIt](https://github.com/jhamlet/node-resolveit)
- [enhanced-resolve](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve)
- [localizer](https://github.com/AndreasMadsen/localizer)

I wrote first, `async-resolve`, and for example:

```
var Resolver = require('async-resolve');
var resolver_obj = new Resolver();
resolver_obj.resolve('module', __dirname, function(err, filename) {
  return console.log(filename);
});
```

It use `node` modules path resolutions rules but don't block main loop as `node` do it. And in result you get filename, so it can be used to decide its local module or global and other things.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 simple solution with 1 line of code :

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function hasDependency(dep) {
        return module.paths.some(modulesPath => fs.existsSync(path.join(modulesPath, dep)));
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with some code comments or some descriptive text in the answer.  A lot of skill levels will find this and it can be easier to sue if it is explained.

Answer (score -9):

using ES6 arrow functions

```
var modulePath = m => { try { return require.resolve(m) } catch(e) { return false } }
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using ES6 arrow functions? Is it worth answering a 3 years old question for this?

Comment: @Florian Margaine the advantage of arrow functions is that all work can be done in one line

Comment: that's not an advantage when you have a try/catch on a single line. Never do that. Seriously.

Comment: @Florian Margaine what about now?

Comment: then there is no advantage to using arrow function.