# How to check in node if module exists and if exists to load?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to check if file/(custom)module js exists under some path. I tried like

`var m = require('/home/test_node_project/per');`
but it throws error when there is no per.js in path. 
I thought to check with
 `fs` if file exists but I don't want to add `'.js'` as suffix if is possible to check without that.
How to check in node if module exists and if exists to load ?

Comment: This has already been asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600684/check-if-a-node-js-module-is-available

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Require is a synchronous operation so you can just wrap it in a try/catch.

```
try {
    var m = require('/home/test_node_project/per');
    // do stuff
} catch (ex) {
    handleErr(ex);
}
```

Comment: Can you think of anything a bit less verbose? I would like to use it inline, something like `const thing = require('path') || {default:'object'}`

Comment: Not really but there's no reason you couldn't make your own require function and do these checks inside it so instead of throwing the error you can return false.

Comment: true. might try that

Answer (score 57):

You can just try to load it and then catch the exception it generates if it fails to load:

```
try {
    var foo = require("foo");
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error && e.code === "MODULE_NOT_FOUND")
        console.log("Can't load foo!");
    else
        throw e;
}
```

You should examine the exception you get just in case it is not merely a loading problem but something else going on. Avoid false positives and all that.

Comment: Why `e instanceof Error` when the catch block is only executed if it **is** an error?

Comment: @WillHoskings In general, in the statement `throw e`, it is possible for `e` to be a primitive type. For instance, you can do `throw "blah"`. If this happens, then the error object you get in `catch (e)` won't be an `Error` object and will fail the test `e instanceof Error`. And it is possible for `x` to be some object, but an object not derived from `Error` at all. You *can* skip `e instanceof Error` if you want. It is up to you do decide whether the 2nd part of the test is "good enough" for you.

Answer (score 23):

It is possible to check if the module is present, without actually loading it:

```
function moduleIsAvailable (path) {
    try {
        require.resolve(path);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Documentation:

> #### [require.resolve(request[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options)
>
> Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

Note: Runtime checks like this will work for Node apps, but they won't work for bundlers like browserify, WebPack, and React Native.

Comment: `require.resolve` tells you whether Node knows about a module. If Node does not know about it, then you cannot load it. However, if Node knows about it, it is no guarantee that it can *load* it. In other words, it is possible for a module to be *known* but not be *available*.

Comment: @Louis please can you give an example.

Comment: A module might pass this check but still fail to load, for example because it has a syntax error, or because it tries to import dependencies which are missing.

Answer (score 8):

You can just check is a folder exists by using methods:

```
var fs = require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Do something
}

// Or

fs.exists(path, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Caching exception would be much nicer

Comment: not enough - you need to check all possible `node_modules` folders and registered extensions (.js .json .node and possibly .coffee)

Comment: +1 This is a good answer because if you use a try-catch you wont know what module is missing, the one specified or a module it depends on, unless reading the error ofc. This solution allows a genuin way to see if a specific module exists.

Comment: i dont recommend this approach alone as file might exist yet it still fails to load. that is why im currently here...