# Splash screen for mobile app deployed to multiple customers and unique for each

Tags: react-native, mobile, splash-screen

We are building a mobile app (in React Native, will run on iOS and Android). The app will have a splash screen. Our system is a multi-tenant platform hosting many customers. We would like to display a unique logo on the splash screen for each customer to brand it. We will only have one mobile app and we won't know the customer until they authenticate (unless we deploy some sort of config with the app).

On the web we use the customer subdomain and set branding based on this (as the subdomain is unique to each customer, ex. client123.ourplatform.com).

We'd obviously like to minimize deployment issues and not have to redeploy a new app each time we add a customer. At the same time, downloading the logo each time will be inefficient.

Is there a capability we could leverage to make this easier to implement? Any samples of doing something similar? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184792/multi-tenancy-in-react-native/37205879#37205879

Comment: Product flavors in android and multiple build targets in iOS is the /bestway. Otherwise you need to have native code written in java and obj.C to render icon based on some API calls or something which is highly inefficient because its the splash screen.

Comment: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config . Look into this as well. Not sure if it supports what you want, but just check