# javascript - Check if an imported module exists in the project and if not use some sort of fallback

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react native module, where i would like to use a common module for a minor thing, but i don't want to force someone to include it just for this.
So i want to check if the module exists, if thats the case use it, if not do a workaround. Code could look something like this:

```
import Module from 'react-native-non-existing-module'

if (Module) {
    // do something with the Module
} else {
    // use fallback
}
```

But i then get an error:

> Error: undefined Unable to resolve module
> `react-native-non-existing-module` from `src/myFile.tsx`:
> react-native-non-existing-module could not be found within the
> project.
>
> If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
>
> 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
> 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
> 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
> 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

I also tried this:
[How to check in node if module exists and if exists to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740309/how-to-check-in-node-if-module-exists-and-if-exists-to-load)
But that didn't work for me either

Comment: Use try catch .... Inside try import the module and if any error write your fallback code inside catch block

Comment: @souravsatyam That's the solution from the other question i linked, but that still gave me the same error.
Maybe i need to tell the bundler somehow to not import that module beforehand?

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why you would import a package you didn't install, if you're in doubt of a particular package, you can easily check your package.json file in the root directory

If what you mean is conditional import, what you'll do  using es6 is

```
 if (condition) {
    import('something')
    .then((something) => {
       console.log(something.something);
   });
}
```

Comment: This is possibly becoming a npm package and i don't want to force a dependency that isn't 100% necessary. But if it is already there then i want to take advantage of it.

Comment: JavaScript will scream once you try to import a missing package. Have you tried checking package. jsom

Comment: It can be very useful to check if a package is installed or not, since NPM allows optional packages.