# Node see if Program is installed

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Hello im making a node app that requires: `ffmpeg, node-acoutstid with fpcalc and eye3D`. 
Now is my question how i can see if those 'programs' are installed on the clients machine.

whats the best way to check this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600684/check-if-a-node-js-module-is-available

Comment: @YiKai no thats not what im looking for im looking for a way to see if X program is installed on the machine for example see if is installed

Comment: You can use nodejs child_process.exec to run a shell command, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 11):

## "shell out" for native detection

In macOS / Linux / bash we'd typically use `command -v` (Posix compliant) or `type -p` or `which` (but don't use those).

In windows there's `where` that you can use like `where node.exe`.

```
require('child_process').exec('type -p mything', function (err, stdout) {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

This naive approach can work if you're not trying to be cross-platform compatible and if you don't have to worry about sanitizing user input.

## Use `command-exists`

On npm there's a package [command-exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-exists). I peeked at the code and it looks like it's probably the simplest cross-platform detection that covers edge cases at a small size:

https://github.com/mathisonian/command-exists/blob/master/lib/command-exists.js

```
var commandExists = require('command-exists');

// invoked without a callback, it returns a promise
commandExists('ls').then(function (command) {
  // proceed
}).catch(function () {
  // command doesn't exist
});
```

Comment: [command-exists](https://github.com/mathisonian/command-exists) npm module has been forked and updated to address this [issue](https://github.com/mathisonian/command-exists/issues/22). its now [command-exists-promise](https://github.com/raftario/command-exists)