# How to check if particular software is installed or not on system using Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to check if Chrome browser is installed or not when my electron app run. I want a solution which will work for all OS.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44065887/2550156

Comment: Thanks for the help. But for windows "where chrome" not working even if chrome is installed.