# Electon optionally load `electron-debug` on a production built app

Tags: npm, electron, production-environment

I found out that [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-debug) plugin offers me some usefull utilities but I do not want as a production depedency to my built application thus I installed it as:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-debug
```

If I place it like that to my code I assume that my production builds will not run because this depedency does not exist:

```
require('electron-debug')();
```

So how I can "optionally" load it and silently suppress any error and continue without any much trouble?

Also [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-debug/blob/master/readme.md) is mentioned :

> Only runs when in development, unless overridden by the enabled option.

But if I use `--save` instead of `--save-dev` I assume that the dependency will be installed on my production built app as well, a dependency that is only used for debugging, and that kinda sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that it won't be included in your production build is correct. So you need a way to know if the module is available.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067955) answer, [Stijn de Witt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286685/stijn-de-witt) presents a way of doing so:

```js
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067955, by Stijn de Witt
function moduleAvailable (name) {
    try {
        require.resolve (name);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        // empty
    }

    return false;
}

// Query for your particular module
if (moduleAvailable ("electron-debug")) require ("electron-debug") ();
```

I'm not too sure of that, but there is a possibility that it also works with packaged (e.g. by `electron-packager`) builds of your app.