# Buidling C++ extention with nbind mysterious warnings

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I am using the [`nbind`](https://github.com/charto/nbind) library, and I am in progress to create a promice in c++ that will be used in an electron application.

So far I follow the [documentation](https://github.com/charto/nbind/blob/master/README.md) instructions and I created the file `./src/cpp/promice.h`:

```
#ifndef PROMICE
#define PROMICE

class MyPromice {
    public:
        MyPromice(){};
        ~MyPromice(){};
        void exec();
};
#endif
```

And my `./src/cpp/promice.cpp`:

```
#include"promice.h"

#include <iostream>
#include<thread>
#include <chrono>

void MyPromice::exec(){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    std::cout << "Executinh Code" << std::endl;
}

#include "nbind/nbind.h"

NBIND_CLASS(MyPromice) {
  method(exec);
}
```

And my `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "electron-cpp-bindings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple test using C++ bindings on an electron app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ./src/",
    "autogypi": "autogypi",
    "node-gyp": "HOME=~/.electron-gyp node-gyp --target=v5.0.6 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers",
    "emcc-path": "emcc-path",
    "copyasm": "copyasm",
    "ndts": "ndts",
    "electron-version": "electron -v",
    "rebuild": "HOME=~/.electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=v5.0.6 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers"
  },
  "author": "Dimitrios Desyllas",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.6",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autogypi": "^0.2.2",
    "nbind": "^0.3.15",
    "node-gyp": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

And my `./src/index.js` is:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
const nbind = require('nbind');
const lib = nbind.init().lib;
const MyPromice=lib.MyPromice;

// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067955, by Stijn de Witt
function moduleAvailable (name) {
  try {
      require.resolve (name);
      return true;
  } catch (e) {
      // empty
  }

  return false;
}

// Query for your particular module
if (moduleAvailable ("electron-debug")) require ("electron-debug") ({showDevTools:false});


// Generic on development configuration
if (env === 'dev' || env === 'debug') {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
}

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.maximize();

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/ui/index.html`);
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  MyPromice.exec();

};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('before-quit', () => {
  if (xmpp) {
    xmpp.disconnect();
  }
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error('Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, ' reason: ', reason);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  if (xmpp) {
    xmpp.disconnect();
  }
  process.exit(0);
});
```

But for some reason when I build with:

```
npm run -- node-gyp   configure build 2> ~/error.txt
```

I get the following stream of errors as seen in [here](https://gist.github.com/pc-magas/190feba740b856a05fce35794c31368d#file-build) (I used gist due to length of output that made my browser crash). Also, the command:

```
npm run rebuild
```

Returns the following output as well as seen in [here](https://gist.github.com/pc-magas/190feba740b856a05fce35794c31368d#file-rebuild)

As far as I understand it seems some sort of linking error. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Please don't link to relevant information on external sites. Include *all* relevant information directly *in* the question.

Comment: Well the releva output made my browser crash due to its size, hence I needed to paste it on gist.

Comment: The error log essentially says that your node version doesn't understand `v8::Handle<>` as a type (AFAIK that type is deprecated in newer node's v8 version). Replace them with `v8::Local<>` in your source

Comment: Therefore `nbind` uses deprecated types right?