# Configuring Jest when multiple paths share the same tsconfig alias

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have been attempting to get Jest working properly with my Typescript configuration and I have been having some issues.

How would one configure the moduleNameMapper inside of the jest.config.js file to allow multiple paths sharing the same alias, such as the example shown in the tsconfig file. With a single path it is not a problem and I would simple set up the path as I have shown in the example Jest.config.js file.

Does anyone have anyone have examples or resources that can help point me in the correct direction?

Thanks in advance.

*Tsconfig.json*

```
compilerOptions: {
  "paths": {
    @app/components: [
      "src/path1/components/*",
      "src/path2/components/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

*Jest.config.js*

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^@app/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/path1/components/$1'
}
```

Comment: paths is rarely ever used with multiple paths. It's ambiguous and that's bad. And it causes problems as you can see. Obviously, this cannot be done with moduleNameMapper because it provides many-to-one or one-to-one mapping. Basically you need custom resolver https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#resolver-string that does this check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067955/3731501 for both paths before requiring it. I'd just refactor imports to avoid the hassle.

Comment: I agree with @EstusFlask. While there are rare situations where it is perfectly reasonable to map with multiple paths, your usage seems highly suspect.